# undefined reference error for g++ but not for gcc when using BSP library

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am making a parallel program for one of my courses. Now initially it was written in C and it all worked just fine. Then we changed it all to c++ and all of a sudden I get some error when I try to compile the program. I am using the package mcbsp (Multicore BSP) for the parallel part. Here is the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mcbsp.h>

void sieve(){
  return ;
}

main(int argc, int **arhv){
  bsp_begin(5);
  printf("%d\n",bsp_pid());
  bsp_end();
  return 0;
}
```

So I make a file aaa.c and aaa.cpp both with this content. Then when I type in the terminal

```
gcc aaa.c -MMD -g -I../bsp/include -L../bsp/lib -lmcbsp1.2.0 -lpthread
```

it compiles just fine and the program does as expected (print the id of the cores). However, when I type

```
g++ aaa.cpp -MMD -g -I../bsp/include -L../bsp/lib -lmcbsp1.2.0 -lpthread
```

it gives the following feedback

```
/tmp/ccH3uox9.o: In function `main':
/home/teun/Documents/C/BSP/Sieve/sieve/aaa.cpp:10: undefined reference to `bsp_begin(unsigned int)'
/home/teun/Documents/C/BSP/Sieve/sieve/aaa.cpp:11: undefined reference to `bsp_pid()'
/home/teun/Documents/C/BSP/Sieve/sieve/aaa.cpp:12: undefined reference to `bsp_end()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have been stuck with this for about an hour now and it is really getting frustrating. I must admit that I have little experience in programming in c++ as I mostly use C. Does anyone know what is going wrong?

EDIT: The program I displayed is just a small working example that uses the BSP functionality.

Comment: I suspect you need to use extern "C" { ... } to surround the C libraries you are using. At the linker stage, C and C++ functions have different "mangled" names.

Comment: Note that many libraries work just fine with C and C++, with conditional logic included in the header files to handle the differences. But the BSP library explicitly only supports C (and Fortran).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple declaration `int bsp_end();` is interpreted differently in C and C++. The reason is that in C++, you can overload functions, which requires that their parameters are included in the symbol name for the linker, see C++ name mangling for further info. Now, since the function is compiled with a C compiler but the declaration is given to a C++ compiler, the symbols don't match and you get linker errors.

As a solution, add `extern "C"` to the function declaration or maybe wrap the whole include:

```
extern "C" {
#include <mcbsp.h>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need `extern "C"` around `#include`

```
 extern " C" {
 #include "c-header.h"
 };
```

This is needed to stop the C++ name mangling